# Nested one-to-one attribute does not save via form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a form with a nested one-to-one attribute which I can't save into the dabase. I've been reading SO threads for four hours to try and solve it:

```
Contact.rb:
class Contact < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

end


Address.rb
class Address < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :contact

end


Routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :contacts do
    resources :addresses
  end

  root :to => 'contacts#index'

end


The form
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :firstname %>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lastname %>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :address do |address_fields| %>
    <%= address_fields.label :streetname %>
    <%= address_fields.text_field :streetname %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>


Controller:
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_contact, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @contacts = Contact.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
    @ontact.build_address
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    if @contact.save
      redirect_to @contact
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  (...)

  private

    def find_contact
      @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    end

    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:firstname, :lastname, 
                            address_attributes: [:contact_id, :streetname])
    end

end
```

With the above code, nothing is saved and the transaction is rolled back. Earlier on, only the contact-details were saved whereas the address remained nil and the following line gave an error that "streetname" was unknown:

```
<p><%= @contact.address.streetname %></p>
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hmm this looks good... Try adding `pp params` and `pp contact_params` at the top of `ContactsController#create` method and report back with the output.

Comment: Thnks @fbelanger. Enclosed the output:

params:
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"w1xQVa4HL8fX7lzx1uA0+52JfkjrnsVm+yxfj/MCJNGnuNZvQRAp7sIzJO+ao3VkcoY738p8gKTkeq9qk0OZxA==", "contact"=>{"firstname"=>"John", "lastname"=>"Doe", "address_attributes"=>{"streetname"=>"Lane"}}, "commit"=>"Create Contact", "controller"=>"contacts", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>

contact_params:
<ActionController::Parameters {"firstname"=>"John", "lastname"=>"Doe", "address_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {"streetname"=>"Lane"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>

Comment: Lol I meant edit your question.

Comment: LoL you're right, noob mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @fbelanger for leading me to the solution:

I noticed from the contents of "params" that permitted was set on false. I found via Google that Rails 5 requires the following addition in the address model, to the belongs_to line:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact, required: false
end
```

And now it's saved: hurray!

Comment: So this was causing `ROLLBACK`, because the contact didn't have an ID yet? Feels weird... wouldn't this render `required: true` utterly useless?